# Copying files based on a condition

Tags: file-copy

Here's the problem I'm attempting to solve:

- Let's say I have a directory "A", containing some files as well as some other directories.
- I want to copy all the files directly under directory A to directory B.
- I want to recursively copy all the folders inside folder A to folder C.

What is the shortest and less platform-specific way to accomplish this in UNIX/Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably something like this

```
find A -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} B/ \;
```

And

```
find A -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec cp -r {} C/ \;
```

Where `-type` is a flag, determining the type you're looking for (file or directory), `- maxdepth` how deep into directory, and `-exec` for executing a command on the result.

Comment: What is the necessity for `-name '*'`?

Comment: @enzotib Good point, I adjusted the answer.

Comment: Would use `find ... \;` for less platform specific.

Comment: Nice, but the second part also copies the entire A directory into C (in addition to the subdirectories). How would I remove that?

Comment: @louism The mindepth flag should prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cp` to copy the directories, giving a glob pattern ending in `/`,

```
cp -a A/*/ C/
```

and you can copy files without the `-a` (similar to `-r`) option

```
cp A/* B/
```

though this last command would give harmless errors on directories not been copied.

Comment: Would use `-R` instead of `-a` for less platform specific.